# Configuring TFS Build Services to Use Proxy Server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

We just got up and running with TFS 2013 Update 4. We migrated from TFS 2010 to 13 on new hardware.

We have TFS running at our main data center. At a different location we have Build Services (controller and agent) running along with a TFS proxy server.  Build services and proxy server are on the same machine, all running under the Network Service account.

We also have Visual Studio (2013 Update 4) on the same server. It is configured to use the proxy server which it does successfully.

But, our builds (using the default TfvcTemplate.12.xaml template) running on the same server do not hit the proxy. They always go back to the main TFS.

I have tweaked the registry as suggested at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716770.aspx

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you restart the build controller once you made the change?

Comment: Yes. I've also restarted the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

The article at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716770.aspx has the right information. However, it doesn't take into consideration what account the build services are running under.

In my case, our Build Configuration was set to run under NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. This account has it's own node in the registry under HKEY_USERS.  It's node is an SID. To get the SID, run the following command from powershell on the server. You may want to add the -filter param to filter to the build service account name.

gwmi -class win32_account

Now, find this node in the registry HKEY_USERS[SID] and add the keys and values mentioned in the article above.

Enabled=True
Url=http://[your proxy server]:[your proxy port]/
AutoConfigured=False

I didn't have to restart any services, but it did take a couple builds before the cache was populated and used.

One other item to keep in mind is the version of TFS being used. In my registry I had nodes for 14.0 and 12.0.  I confirmed which one was being used by running [Process Monitor from SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) filtering to registry data and then running a build.